# Instagram /media/search radius and shape

Tags: api, instagram, endpoints

I am playing with Instagram's **/media/search** endpoint and have two questions:

1) One can set the distance around the point (lat/lng) one is searching at. When I try to map my results it looks like the points are within a rectangle and not a circle. Can anyone confirm that ?

2) I a recursively stepping back in time. using max_timestamp. Does anyone know how far one can go back in time ?

Answer (score 0):

1. The distance is the radius, it searches within a circle.
2. I just checked, I can only go back as far as July 2013.

Here is an implementation of location search, you can change radius and date/time: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map